# Run a gdb macro for all files in a directory

Tags: shell, gdb

I want to create a macro for which a directory path will be given. The macro in-turn has to run another macro for all the files in the directory. Is that possible in gdb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the macro you want to run is a gdb macro. To solve this, I suggest you use the Python support in gdb to encompass this. Put the following in `forallindir.py`

```
import gdb
import os

class ForAllInDir (gdb.Command):
  "Executes a gdb-macro for all files in a directory."

def __init__ (self):
  super (ForAllInDir, self).__init__ ("forallindir",
                                      gdb.COMMAND_SUPPORT,
                                      gdb.COMPLETE_NONE, True)

def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):
  arg_list = gdb.string_to_argv(arg)
  path = arg_list[0]
  macro = arg_list[1]
  for filename in os.listdir(path):
    gdb.execute(macro + ' ' + os.path.join(path, filename))

ForAllInDir()
```

Then in gdb to `source forallindir.py` and it should work. For example, define a test macro like

```
define testit
  print "i got called with $arg0"
end
```

and `forallindir /tmp/xx testit` with two sample files in that directory will give us

```
$1 = "i got called with /tmp/xx/ape"
$2 = "i got called with /tmp/xx/bear"
```

Hope that helps.